# wxPython method to handle EVT_MOVE event

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to learn wxPython and have come across the following code (when the user moves the window it prints their current window position):

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame): 

   def __init__(self, *args, **kw): 
      super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw)  
      self.InitUI() 

   def InitUI(self): 
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE, self.OnMove) 
      self.SetSize((250, 180)) 
      self.SetTitle('Move event') 
      self.Centre() 
      self.Show(True)

   def OnMove(self, e): 
      x, y = e.GetPosition() 
      print "current window position x = ",x," y= ",y 

ex = wx.App() 
Example(None) 
ex.MainLoop()
```

My problem specifically is with the `OnMove` method,  I understand that it is used to handle `EVT_MOVE` events but where is the parameter `e` coming from? What object is this?

Answer (score 0):

It is the `event` that you bound to, in this case `EVT_MOVE`.

In essence you used `self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE, self.OnMove)` to bind the `EVT_MOVE` event of the Frame (self) to the execution of the function `OnMove`. The result being that whenever the event is fired, i.e. the frame is moved, the code in `OnMove` is executed.

See: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html

if you altered your code to be:

```
   def OnMove(self, event): 
      x, y = event.GetPosition() 
      print "current window position x = ",x," y= ",y
```

it would be more obvious.

> Bind(self, event, handler, source=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, id2=wx.ID_ANY)
>   Bind an event to an event handler.
>
> Parameters:
>   event – One of the EVT_ event binder objects that
>   specifies the type of event to bind.
>
> handler – A callable object to be
>   invoked when the event is delivered to self. Pass None to disconnect
>   an event handler.
>
> source – Sometimes the event originates from a
>   different window than self, but you still want to catch it in self.
>   (For example, a button event delivered to a frame.) By passing the
>   source of the event, the event handling system is able to
>   differentiate between the same event type from different controls.
>
> id
>   – Used to specify the event source by ID instead of instance.
>
> id2 –
>   Used when it is desirable to bind a handler to a range of IDs, such as
>   with EVT_MENU_RANGE.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer this. I am still a little unclear though, does Bind() pass the event to OnMove() when the window is moved?